# HTTP: what is the correct way to send "retry/redirect" response

Tags: java, http, web, http-headers

I need to force the client to retry its request (meaning to send the same request one more time). What I'm thinking of is a response with status-code `307` and header `Location: <original-url>` (that's good enough for now, unless there's a better way).

My question is, from HTTP specification point of view, what is the correct value for `Location` in this specific context. Or more specifically in Java having `request` of type `HttpServletRequest`, which one should I use: `getRequestURI` (Returns the part of this request's URL from the protocol name up to the query string in the first line of the HTTP request) or `getRequestURL` (Reconstructs the URL the client used to make the request containing protocol, server name, port number, and server path, but it does not include query string parameters).

Any other suggestion/comment is appreciated.

Comment: This definitely requires more information: Do you wish to force the client to refresh the content? Or are you queueing processing?

Comment: A little bit of context: the server cannot process the request because it's shutting down. However if the client closes the connection and open a new connection and sends the very same request (same method, headers, body, everything), he will be connected to another server which is up and running. Please see my comment to Julian's answer.

Answer (score 1):

getRequestURL() returns complete URL used by the client where as getRequestURI() returns just the basic path resides in server.
i am using this technique to redirect with a response status this is my code this is useful:-

```
httpServletResponse.reset();
httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
httpServletResponse.setHeader("SERVER-RESPONSE", "bad request");
return;
```

and also you can set headers in response.

Comment: That for the info, but my question was specifically about the header.

Comment: don't use send redirect or request dispatcher to redirect the request i updated my code with header setting block..

Comment: IMO definitely neither `Bad Request` nor `Unauthorized` is a valid option here. They are by definition client's fault, which is not the case in this scenario. Clients should not retry the very same request after receiving `Bad Request` or `Unauthorized`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a redirect is the wrong status code in the first place.

Isn't this what 503 is for? (https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#status.503)

Comment: Well AFAIK there's no status code specifically defined for such situation. I found different suggestions on the web (for slightly different scenarios): 503, 307, 302, 423, 409, or 202.

Comment: The reason I picked 307 because most clients do the redirecting automatically. But (as you already know) the catch is that for methods other than GET and HEAD they don't (according to HTTP spec). Nevertheless I see the potential of `503` if we set `Retry-After` header. The problem is that 5XX responses is the last thing we like to have in our logs.